How to pass environment variables to a reusable workflow in Github Actions
In the GitHub actions console I have an environment created for my workflow. This environment has certain variables like account_number etc. I want to pass this value into the resuable workflow.
name: Deploying Lambda

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]
    branches:
      - 'dev'

jobs:

 unit-tests-execution:
 # job details here

 my-job:
   needs: unit-tests-execution
   uses: myorg/myrepo/.github/workflows/reusable.yml@v1.0.0
   with:
     ACCOUNT: <assign the variable account_number from the DEV environment here>

How to assign the variable account_number saved in the DEV environment created in the Github console to the reusable workflow input variable ACCOUNT?
If I do this below I get an error saying environment: can't be used with uses:
 my-job:
   needs: unit-tests-execution
   environment: DEV
   uses: myorg/myrepo/.github/workflows/reusable.yml@v1.0.0
   with:
     ACCOUNT: ${{ vars.account_number}}

I don't want to set the environment in the reusable.yml workflow because that workflow will be used for different accounts and should have just the account number passed in.

Variables don't pass into the called workflows, but it looks like you should be able to use workflow inputs and pass the inputs in using with.

Variables don't propagate into the called workflows, but you can use workflow inputs and pass the values in using with.
I have created and tested this minimal example illustrating the technique:
.github/workflows/reusable.yml:
name: Worflow with input
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      my-arg:
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  print_input:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: display my arg
        run: echo ${{ inputs.my-arg }}

.github/workflows/reuser.yml:
name: reuser
on:
  - push
jobs:
  reuser:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable.yml
    with:
      my-arg: top level reuser

My sources are the GitHub Actions manual:

workflow inputs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows?ref=sethduke.io#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow
providing input values: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows?ref=sethduke.io#passing-inputs-and-secrets-to-a-reusable-workflow

